# Is it necessary to use StandardScaler on y_train and y_test? If yes, cases?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

Have read multiple cases where StandardScaler is used on y_train and y_test and also where it is not used. Is there any specific rules where it should be used on them?

Comment: When your features have different scales you should standardize their values.

Comment: This is a better question for the [stats.se] or [datascience.se] stack sites, as it has to do with theory rather than a specific coding issue

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111467/is-it-necessary-to-scale-the-target-value-in-addition-to-scaling-features-for-re

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html):

> Standardization of a dataset is a common requirement for many machine
>   learning estimators: they might behave badly if the individual
>   features do not more or less look like standard normally distributed
>   data (e.g. Gaussian with 0 mean and unit variance).
>
> For instance many elements used in the objective function of a
>   learning algorithm (such as the RBF kernel of Support Vector Machines
>   or the L1 and L2 regularizers of linear models) assume that all
>   features are centered around 0 and have variance in the same order. If
>   a feature has a variance that is orders of magnitude larger that
>   others, it might dominate the objective function and make the
>   estimator unable to learn from other features correctly as expected.

So probably When your features has different scales/distributions you should standardize/scale their values.